# How can I apply a pixel shader to a canvas element?

Tags: html, canvas, webgl, fragment-shader

I have a `<canvas>` element which is written to by an external library. I wish to apply a "post-production" effect to this canvas: I want to map a function `(r,g,b,a) -> (r,g,b,a)` over every pixel before it is finally displayed.

I know that the external library writes to a 2D context obtained from the `<canvas>` element. I also know that the transformation I'm asking for is a "pixel shader" or "fragment shader". I know I will need a `webgl` context to apply such a shader. I am told by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8466639/229792) that a canvas cannot have multiple contexts at the same time, so I am not sure this approach is possible.

Another approach I considered is to capture the output of the canvas as a stream, and write it to a new canvas with my transformation applied. However, [this feature only exists in bleeding-edge Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStream/canvas).

**Is it possible to apply a fragment shader to canvas output? If so, how?**

Comment: you don't have to use `captureStream()`, `CanvasContext2D.drawImage()` method does accept an other canvas as imageSource. You would then just have to create an other canvas element, and `drawImage(yourActualCanvas, 0, 0)` on it. If the canvas drawn is not tainted, you can call the `getImageData()` of the canvas to do your pixel transformation, or you may also find your happiness into [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) which are way faster !

Comment: Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/an0ajbfw/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy a 2D canvas to a WebGL texture and render that texture to a WebGL canvas with whatever fragment shader you design.

There's plenty of examples on stack overflow of using a canvas as the source data for a texture

[How Do I Use an HTML5 Canvas as a WebGL Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570235/how-do-i-use-an-html5-canvas-as-a-webgl-texture)

[how to get texture in webgl?without Canvas.toDataUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813005/how-to-get-texture-in-webglwithout-canvas-todataurl)

[Blend two canvases onto one with WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590685/blend-two-canvases-onto-one-with-webgl)

[WebGL blit texture to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449599/webgl-blit-texture-to-canvas)